# Проблема с кодировкой в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, кодировка

У меня на сайте отображается всё хорошо, кроме статей, то есть, текст статей показывает вот так Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ. В header.php стоит кодировка UTF-8, сайт отображается хорошо, а вот текст статей нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите, как вы выводите content. Чувствую, производите над ним строковые операции

Comment: В каком-таком "header.php стоит кодировка UTF-8"? Настраивай правильно хостинг и базу и будет тебе счастье :)